# Does Docker USER source .bashrc before running commands?

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile

I have a Docker file where I'm running along the lines of:

```
FROM centos:6.7
...
...
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash my_user \
 && echo "my_user:docker" | chpasswd \
 && echo "my_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers \
 && chown my_user:my_user /home/my_user \
 && chmod 755 /home/my_user \
 && mkdir -p /home/my_user/.ssh
...
RUN echo "export HELLO=WORLD" >> /home/my_user/.bashrc
...
USER my_user
ENV FLASK_APP=/path/to/my/app.py
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The Flask server, upon getting the correct web request, simply executes the following:

```
procedure = subprocess.Popen("/my/cool/program", shell=False)
```

However, the program fails to find the `HELLO` environment variable. When I force the environment into the command by doing

```
env_dict = {
    'HELLO': 'WORLD'
}

procedure = subprocess.Popen("/my/cool/program", shell=False, env=env_dict)
```

It works without issue. This is making me believe that the issue is that when docker runs the `CMD` as the user selected with `USER`, it doesn't first source that's user's environment properly.

Is that true? If so, is there any good way around it? I'd like to avoid double declaring all my env variables in both the `.bashrc` and in the Flask app.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with bash as your command:

```
CMD ["bash", "-c", "flask run --host 0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do it, though I feel like this should work. I'll do more testing and report back. I wonder if it's more of a Python `Popoen` thing than a Docker thing.